# How to solve AttributeError: 'Audio' object has no attribute 'transcribe'?

Tags: openai-api, voice, whisper, elevenlabs

Hello i am trying to do a voicebot.
I wrote following code;

app.py

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()
from interface import AudioInterface
interface=AudioInterface()
text=interface.listen()
print(text)
interface.speak(text)
```

interface.py

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import os
from elevenlabs import generate, play, set_api_key

set_api_key(os.environ['ELEVEN_API_KEY'])

class AudioInterface:

    def listen(self)->str:
        recognizer=sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("say something")
            audio=recognizer.listen(source)
        text=recognizer.recognize_whisper_api(
            audio, 
            api_key=os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
        )
        return text
            
    def speak(self, text):
        audio=generate(
            text=text,
            voice='Bella',
            model='eleven_monolingual_v1'
        )
        play(audio)
```

Actually there is no need to import elevenlabs to get this error, you can delete that part from the code.

error on ;
text=interface.listen()

```
(venv) sk@Sevval-MacBook-Air voice_assistant % python src/app.py            
say something
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sk/Dev/search-gpt/voice_assistant/src/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    text=interface.listen()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sk/Dev/search-gpt/voice_assistant/src/interface.py", line 15, in listen
    text=recognizer.recognize_whisper_api(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sk/Dev/search-gpt/voice_assistant/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/speech_recognition/recognizers/whisper.py", line 43, in recognize_whisper_api
    transcript = client.audio.transcribe(model, wav_data, api_key=api_key)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Audio' object has no attribute 'transcribe'
```

openai Version: 1.14.1

Comment: This code does not refer to a `.transcribe` attribute, therefore the error must be happening in other code that you have not shown us.  It's very hard to help when you do not show the code that has the actual error.  Please post the full traceback error message.

Comment: hello, yes there is no transcribe because its comes from the lib, i edited the post @JohnGordon